# Linux: printf to fulled stdout

Tags: c, linux

What if I use printf to output string to fulled buffer stdout?

printf will wait forever in write() function?

By the way, stdout is used share for system or each process?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: I don't know mechanism stdout, that why I add this question.
If I wrong. please help to corect me

Comment: @PaulRooney judging by comments below, i think he is asking about what happens if the program writes so much data that the buffer of stdout fills up

Comment: @Paul Rooney: I updated my question for buffer stdout

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Each process gets its own stdout file descriptor and it shouldn't conflict with another program's. The only reason it might hang in write is if the output buffer is full... E.g. If you're redirecting the output of the application.

Comment: thank you.
I am facing the hang issue when when I printf to stdout, it hang in write function. But I don't know the reason


#0  0x004ad430 in __kernel_vsyscall ()  
#1  0x009d782b in write () from /lib/libc.so.6  
#2  0x00971224 in _IO_new_file_write () from /lib/libc.so.6  
#3  0x00972b00 in _IO_new_do_write () from /lib/libc.so.6  
#4  0x00971cb2 in _IO_new_file_overflow () from /lib/libc.so.6  
#5  0x00970e62 in _IO_new_file_xsputn () from /lib/libc.so.6  
#6  0x009499bf in vfprintf () from /lib/libc.so.6  

Do you know this?

Comment: Can you provide your code and also include the command line you're using to run the program?

Comment: My pseudo code like this  
  
    for (;;)  
    {  
       char str[128] = "";
        gettimeofday(&tv,NULL);  
        local_t = localtime(&tv.tv_sec);
        sprintf (str , 128,  "%02d:%02d:%02d", tmp->tm_hour, tmp->tm_min, tmp->tm_sec};  
        printf ("%s", str );  
    }

Comment: Where do you declare/define str? That's probably the issue. Edit: Well also it looks like you're running it in a tight infinite loop, which could fill up the output buffer (if the output is buffered)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the declaration of `str`.  How could it?  It's a simple matter of doing blocking I/O on `stdout`, as I explained very clearly in my answer.  Read it if you want to know what's really going on.

Comment: @TomKarzes: Thanks for your comment. I read it. but I don't know  whether printing string to console is blocking or non-blocking. In my case, I am printing the time string in str[] array to console.
Is it blocking?

Comment: @bvp147 if it's not too much to ask, I'd still like to see how you're instantiating and declaring str just in case

Comment: @bvp147 It's probably blocking (normally the default).  You can test it by calling `fcntl` and doing `F_GETFL` on file descriptor 1 (i.e., stdout).  It's not clear to me why it would block if you're writing to the console though.  Usually output blocks when writing to a pipe, and the consumer isn't keeping up (or is stopped or waiting for something else).  Have you tried directing the output to a file to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @bvp147 I had another thought.  This may be a simple buffering issue.  Does your output end in a newline?  If not, and if `stdout` is being line buffered, then it may simply be holding the string in its buffer, in which case you wouldn't see it until some time later.  I suggest making sure it ends with a newline `\n` character.  You can also call `fflush(stdout);`  after the `printf` call to force it to flush `stdout`.

Comment: @kcraigie: I just declare a local array str[] to store time string. then I print to console. nothing to do much. my above code is call in many thread (about 256) and run parallely

Comment: @Tom Karzes: I see. I run about 12h then hang occur.
I try fflush (stdout) after printf. but it is hung again.
I 'm running again and redirect to text file.

Comment: @bvp147 Keep in mind that if you redirect to a file, it typically won't be line buffered, but will instead be buffered solely on the number of characters in the buffer.  But again, you can force it to flush by calling `fflush(stdout)`, which is probably a good idea while you're debugging this.

Comment: @Tom Karzes: I run my code long time, in many thread (256 threads at the same time) and I redirect the printf result to file, no print directly on console as before. Result is OK, no hang occur. I think that my problem when print to console is overflow buffer stdout, because many thread run paralle

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what it's writing to, and whether it's using blocking- vs. non-blocking I/O.  Typically it's blocking by default.  But keep in mind that `printf` buffers its output, so you may not know if there was a problem until `stdout` is flushed.  If you really want to know if there was a problem, you should check the return value from `fclose`.

Another possibility is that the buffer is simply not being flushed.  Usually `stdout` is line buffered, which means it gets flushed when a newline character is written.  You can force it to flush by calling `fflush(stdout);` to see if that makes a difference.  I also suggest making sure your output ends with a newline character.

Comment: Thank you. But I try adding the fflush(stdout) after printf. The hang occur again.